# How to calculate memory utilization for MIG in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, metrics

Could you please explain how resources utilization are calculated for MIG in GCP.

I have MIG with 2 instances. I use Metrics explorer for checking.
When I use filter by instance group I got result about **50%**. But when filter by instances (for both result very similar) I get about **85%**.

Comment: You should not filter on the same thing or on the same time windows. The memory usage is always the ratio of the used memory over the total of memory. Either on 1 VM, or on a group of VM.